# What are components more important in a Login interface - System?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, design, interface, responsive-design

I made a system web for administration information and my customer solicit me a interface elegant and professional and like he is  a people older and he doest not knows a lot about how to workings  the system web and just he wants to a system for add information about him company small,  some idea of that are components more important in a login access interface?

[image]

[image]

if you want to check out  the  demo web beta, check out here:

[demo](https://aqueous-reef-94191.herokuapp.com)

**I need some help of a expert people from here**

Answer (score 2):

I like the footer approach the best.

Maybe with a phone number in case they need help with the login or have any other question.

Also after translating "Inicia sesion en tu cuenta" -> "Log in to your account"

The user if he's not experienced enough might as "What account?"

So I would replace that text with a company logo and also a descriptive text saying something like:

Login to the Administrative portal of sales orders (or whatever it is that you do)

Then you tell the user what they actually are logging into.

Comment: Also after translating "Inicia sesion en tu cuenta" -> "Log in to your account"

 my website is in spanish no in english

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what your text said. I had to translate it for myself. I didn't tell you to change it to english.

I merely suggested that you add what you're trying to sign into. If you would like to translate that to Spanish or Swahili that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

In every login screen need username, password , forget password link and remember me checkbox.

If you provide user id and password by admin then no need to give signup or registration link otherwise you need to give registration or signup link too.

This are essentials components for Login screen.